# Is there a better way to find IP address of a running instance other than using DescribeAddressesRequest?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

As the title says, I am using [DescribeAddressesRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeAddressesRequest.html) in order to find out what IP address(es) are given to an instance after its creation. I wonder is there a way to give IPs assigned to *particular* instance (with, say, instance ID `i-b4b4d3d4`)?

The approach I am using, described above, gives me potentially thousands of Addresses, which is inconvenient as I am always interested in a single instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on the instance then you'd use the the various metadata suppled via the web portal at 169.254.169.254.  Use `EC2MetadataUtils` or a `HttpClient` in Java or:

```
curl -o - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

For a full list of metadata use:

```
curl -o - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

If you are talking about *filtering* the `DescribeAddressesRequest` in Java then you can add filters.  Something like this should work I think:

```
DescribeAddressesRequest request =
    new DescribeAddressesRequest().withFilters(
        Arrays.asList(new Filter().withName("resource-id").withValues("i-b4b4d3d4")));
```

Might be `"instance-id"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to know an instance's Public IP address, then you could use `setFilters()` on the `DescribeAddressesRequest` call.

Here's the equivalent using the AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --filter Name=instance-id,Values=i-abcd1234 --query 'Addresses[*].PublicIp'
```